# How to transform a Page-based App into a Tab-Based App (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any way in Xcode, if you selected one of the preset app formats, to remove that format and implement something else? (Without creating a new app.)

Currently I have a page-based (looks like a book) app with only one "page" and it would make a lot more sense to implement this app using tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Tab bar Member IbOutlet in appdelegate.
 add it as root view controller on window.

take different navigation controller for each tab.
Connect each navigation bar with expected Viewcontroller.

That is the major advantage of Viewcontroller based application.